# SecurityError: "cross-origin object" with window.open popup on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-domain

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054965/securityerror-on-cross-origin-object-with-window-open)

I'm creating two react apps, one on port 3000 and the other one on port 3001, both in localhost. The project on localhost:3000 is an signin api, similar to google oauth. The app on localhost:3001 needs to open an popup to allow user to login on localhost:3000 and finally return the user account to localhost:3001.

localhost:3001 relevant code:

```js
let browser = window.self;
browser.onSuccess = function (res) {
    // Do something
}
browser.open("http://localhost:3000/singin", "Sign in", opts);
```

localhost:3000 relevant code:

```js
// Set document domain to same domain of window.opener
document.domain = "localhost:3001";
// Call onSuccess function
window.opener.onSuccess(user);
```

The function exists, but when its called it throws the following error:
**SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "onSuccess" on cross-origin object**.

Belive it or not, yesterday it was working just fine after set **document.domain** equals to **localhost:3001**.

What I tried:

- Add this header on index.html of localhost:3000:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="localhost:3001/">
```

- Add a protocol (like "http://") to "document.domain".
- Allow firewall access to both ports (I was desperate ok?)

### Edit

Code for localhost:3001 [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ahjgfd?file=src/App.js). Files in src/localhost3000 are from localhost:3001 project.

### Please

I **DON'T** want to use postMessage.

Comment: What other scripts are you importing

Comment: @Joe, I just added a link for some code

Answer (score 1):

According to [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) docs, I don't think it is possible

> If the opener is not on the same origin as the current page,
> functionality of the opener object is limited. For example, variables
> and functions on the window object are not accessible. However,
> navigation of the opener window is possible, which means that the
> opened page can open an URL in the original tab or window. In some
> cases, this makes phishing attacks possible, where a trusted page that
> is opened in the original window is replaced by a phishing page by the
> newly opened page.

If you own both domains, it's pretty easy and simple to connect both with postMessage.

Comment: By reading the documentation, I would agree with you. But as I said, it was working fine yesterday, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456825/when-page-is-opened-with-window-open-how-can-the-opened-page-allow-the-opener-t) adding document.domain should work, the author answered the question itself. Now I'm very confused

Comment: Seems [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) it's a deprecated feature, it might be why it used to work. Also the autor mention IE11, no newest browser.

Comment: Yep, I can't explain why was working before. But I can tell that only worked after I set document.domain. After a little more of research, I decide to use postMessage. Thank you @uke. You're the best.